# Gaps on CV on Linkedin

Tags: resume, employment-gaps

I have work experience of roughly 7-8 years. I have linkedin profile.
The thing is during my career, I have two gaps, one roughly 4-5 months, other similar - none of them more than 6 months.

The way I have currently "hidden" this on Linkedin is I show only employment years, on my original CV I have months included.

What is the way to go - for Linkedin? Shall I put months there too, or this is unneccesary and I may make others suspicious for no real reason(none of the two gaps were because I was fired or smth like that; one was because I left job in a different country due to health condition. Other was I quit my job planning to start a different job in other country, but changed my mind in last moment).

PS. I am interested specifically about linkedin situation.

PPS. And yeah... it is not only for interviews as someone might not invite you to interview from linkedin anyway. Just about impression they may get when looking at my Linkedin etc..

Comment: Have you checked some of the highest-voted question on the employment-gaps tag? Several of those offer good advice on how to handle gaps in a resume. Apart from that, your question is probably too broad and opinion-based for this site, consider rewording it to focus on a single question like "Should I hide an employment gap by not mentioning months in my work history?"

Answer (score 3):

Nobody can give you a definitive answer as to how prospective employers will react to this, as it is up to their own personal preferences.

So, in my opinion, as an employer I would not be worried about some small gaps in employment time, however my own curious nature would likely lead me to ask you about them in an interview.  In your question you don't mention what you were doing during these time gaps.  If it is something you are comfortable talking about, such as travelling or just wanting some personal time with the family, then there is nothing to be worried about.

On the other hand, if you are not comfortable talking about it, obscuring the months by only listing the years could help you avoid that conversation.  I would probably still ask you about it in an interview ("So, did you work at company X for the full 2 years you have listed here?"), but some employers might not even notice, since it's not uncommon for people to be a little unsure of what months they started or ended a job in.

Either way, it would never stop me from considering you for an interview.